# how to lock mutexes and signal conditional variables on a map entries?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt, pthreads

I have in RAM Repository in my Qt application:

```
struct mutexData{
    pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
    pthread_cond_t* condition;
};

/**
 * in memory database implementation shared pointers to records are kept on the 
 * free store as this is the way std::vector allocates its elements
 * records itself are also on heap because this is the way we allocate them
 * in PosixClient callbacks
 */
class Repository {
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<pthread_mutex_t> mutex_ptr;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<pthread_cond_t> cond_ptr;

    typedef std::map<const IBAdditions::ContractEvent, 
                        std::vector<IBAdditions::rec_ptr> > ContractEventDataMap;
    typedef std::map<const IBAdditions::ContractEvent, mutexData> 
                                           ContractEventMutexMap;

    Repository(const std::vector<IBAdditions::ContractEvent>& contractEventVector);
    Repository();
    virtual ~Repository();

    /**
     * insert record into repository
     * @param ce key to the map, IB::Contract and IBAdditions::Event
     * @param rptr record to be stored into repository
     */
    void putRecord(const IBAdditions::ContractEvent ce, 
                   const IBAdditions::rec_ptr rptr);

    /**
     * get a reference to corresponding vector based on ContactEvent key
     * @param contractEvent
     * @return reference to vector of records
     */
    std::vector<IBAdditions::rec_ptr>& operator[](const 
                  IBAdditions::ContractEvent& contractEvent){
        return contractEventDataMap_[contractEvent];
    }

private:
    Repository(const Repository& orig);
    ContractEventDataMap contractEventDataMap_;
    ContractEventMutexMap contractEventMutexMap_;
};
```

Now, I have main thread which will constantly put records into repository vectors for ContractEvents (key). When a new record for a given ContractEvent appears I want specific GUI object to compute something based on data from Repository vectors. So such object requires access to multiple repo entries then. I think about such design that object has posix thread waiting on conditional variables and when each incoming record will be then put into repo, `Repository::putRecord` function will wake up sleeping threads waiting on this conditional variable (on this vector). Is this a good design? Secondly, how should mutexes be added? On each vector or one mutex on full Repo? Do I need to guard access on full map or on each entry? Can one thread use vector1, vector2 data, and other use vector3 and vector4 data simultaneously? Or is this a concurrent access (the same map actually)?

I want to each object starting its own computation when there is a new record in vector in which it is interested. I will have for example 8 objects each requiring access to 2 or more vectors, some may overlap, so I thought every each vector has to be guarded. I want each object do on its own for parallelism. What if two objects try to access same vector?

Currently I think about something like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param ce key to the map, IB::Contract and IBAdditions::Event
 * @param rptr record to be stored into repository
 * TODO: lock mutex here before push_back into Repository
 * and wake up waiting threads
 */
void Repository::putRecord(const IBAdditions::ContractEvent ce, 
                             const IBAdditions::rec_ptr rptr) {
    if(contractEventDataMap_.find(ce) == contractEventDataMap_.end()){
        /* 
         * there is no such ContractEvent in the map
         * next available mutex's identifier is contractEventDataMap_.size()
         * ( before inserting ce into contractEventDataMap_ )
         */
        printf("[Repository:putRecord] locking mutex %d\n",
                                              contractEventDataMap_.size());
        mutexData m;
        m.mutex = &repoMutexes[contractEventDataMap_.size()];
        m.condition = &repoConditions[contractEventDataMap_.size()];
        contractEventMutexMap_[ce] = m;

        contractEventDataMap_[ce] = std::vector<IBAdditions::rec_ptr>();
    }
    printf("[Repository] vector size is;%d\n", contractEventDataMap_[ce].size());
    contractEventDataMap_[ce].push_back(rptr);
    printf("[Repository] vector size is;%d\n", contractEventDataMap_[ce].size());
}
```

Comment: The number of mutexes you want is influenced by the concurrency you need.  If you need this to keep 2 cores busy then one mutex will get you a long ways.

Comment: I will have for example 8 objects each requiring access to 2 or more vectors, some may overlap, so I thought every each vector has to be guarded. I want each object do on its own for parallelism. What if two objects try to access same vector?

Comment: I want to each object starting its own computation when there is a new record in vector in which it is interested